# how to call webservice using jquery 1.0.pack?

Tags: jquery

Is there any possibility to call webservice using jQuery 1.0.pack.js?

Comment: jQuery 1.0? That is fairly old. Are you stuck with it for some reason?

Comment: yes i want to know whether the web service calling method is there or not in  jQuery 1.0.pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [jQuery Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the `$.ajax()` method was added in version 1.0. You can use this method to call remote web services.

```
jQuery.ajax( settings )                            version added: 1.0
```

You can see the 1.0 API documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.0/).